# NSData decompression taking too much time / slow

Tags: ios, swift, compression, nsdata

Basically I have simple `Codable` struct I want to save to disk with compression using `lz4` algorithm, which seems to be the fastest one. Compresses with no problem and very fast, takes 2 ms, but decompressing same data takes 1700 ms.

What's wrong?

```
struct MyDataStruct: Codable {
    var subStructs: [SubStructData]
}
struct SubStructData: Codable {
    var a: String = "a"
    var b: String = "b"
    var c: Int = 1
}

class DataExporter {
    
    var compressedData = NSData()
    
    func saveData() {
    
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        
        // Generate dummy data
        var myDataStruct = MyDataStruct(subStructs: [])
        myDataStruct.subStructs = (0...350_000).map { _ in
            return SubStructData()
        }
        
        // Encode
        let data = try! encoder.encode(myDataStruct) as NSData
        print(".........rawData: \(data.count / 1_000) KB")
        
        // Compress
        let start = DispatchTime.now()
        
        compressedData = try! data.compressed(using: .lz4)
        
        let end = DispatchTime.now()
        let nanoTime = end.uptimeNanoseconds - start.uptimeNanoseconds
        let timeInterval = Double(nanoTime) / 1_000_000
        
        print("..compressedData: \(compressedData.count / 1_000) KB, took \(timeInterval) ms.")
        
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        
        // Decompress
        let start = DispatchTime.now()
        
        let decompressedData = try! compressedData.decompressed(using: .lz4)
        
        let end = DispatchTime.now()
        let nanoTime = end.uptimeNanoseconds - start.uptimeNanoseconds
        let timeInterval = Double(nanoTime) / 1_000_000
        
        print("decompressedData: \(decompressedData.count / 1_000) KB, took \(timeInterval) ms.")
        
    }
}
```

`saveData()` then `loadData()` prints;

```
.........rawData: 8400 KB
..compressedData: 49 KB, took 1.910732 ms.
decompressedData: 8400 KB, took 1702.779161 ms.
```

Comment: On my machine, I see this process take 600ms, which is much shorter than your time, but also still significantly longer than the compression time. However: this doesn't necessarily mean anything is _wrong_ — you're compressing and decompressing 350,000 records... All of the compression algorithms take much longer on decode than encode for this size of input, and they're all doing a decently large amount of work. If you compare the results here to a different tool (e.g. a command-line LZ4 decoder), what time do you see?

Comment: It might be worth noting that compression algorithms are non-linear (i.e., 2x the size of the input might require more than 2x time to perform the work) — you might gain some insight here by reducing the number of records, repeating the above code, and graphing the results (number of records vs. time).

Comment: The decompression should be faster than compression but in your case you must alloc memory which may cost time. I check that with smaller amount of data compression/decompressions are more as these should be : for map size < 8192 compression is slower that decompression.  If map size > 8200, compression start to be faster and the difference seems exponential

Comment: Something is very wrong if compression takes 2 ms and decompression takes 1700 ms. Are you sure you are measuring what you think you're measuring?

Comment: @ItaiFerber I'm going to use this compression on iOS device so I've tried on device(iPad) it's faster compared to XCode simulator but still takes 250x compression time to decompress.

Comment: @PtitXav This was very helpful, thanks. I haven't thought about lowering the records because my data model will have maybe millions of records. I guess I have to split them then?

Comment: @x670 What do the timings look like with the actual data you want to store? This sample here seems unlikely to be representative of your real-world data — it's an extreme edge case of many, many repetitions of a small, fixed chunk of data, which is quite possibly be why it's _so_ fast to compress. With real data, what differences are you seeing?

Comment: @ItaiFerber With real life data for the same amount(350k records) it's ~1300ms to compress, ~8500ms to decompress. It makes more sense now but still it's very slow for me. Is there any other method to store this many data faster?

Comment: @x670 That depends very much on the specifics of how you need to store the data, whether you need to interoperate with other APIs, etc (e.g., are you compressing this data just to take up less space on disk, or are you transmitting it over the network?). For this many records, it's generally much more common to use something like a database, which is much more optimized (both for storage and speed), but it depends on whether you can use one. We'd need a lot more detail there to make specific recommendations